# Add Mouse Listener to Table Model Class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, tablemodel

I am developing a desktop application with in Java and with the NetBeans 8.0 IDE
 there is a `JTable` that uses a custom table model that extends an`AbstractTableModel`. Is it possible to implement a mouse listener in the table model class by implementing the `MouseListener` interface?

I have tried to do that but looks like am stuck for now. And I do not want to use the `JTable` class.

Any advice. the code snippet for the table model is given below.

```
   public class CourseTableModel  extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener , 
   MouseListener {

  private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
  private String[] header = { "ID","COURSE","YEAR GRADUATED "};

 private int minRowCount = 5;
 public Object rawData = null;
 Object[]  cl = null;

 public CourseTableModel()
 { super(); }

 public List<List<Object>> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
 }

 public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {  
    this.dataList = dataList;
    fireTableDataChanged();       
    fireTableStructureChanged();        
 }

 @Override
 public int getRowCount() {
    return Math.max(minRowCount, dataList.size());
 }

 @Override
 public int getColumnCount() {
    return header.length;
 }

  public void setHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
  }

  public String[] getHeader() {
    return header;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    if(row < dataList.size())      
    {rawData = dataList.get(row).get(col);}
    return rawData;
   }

  @Override
  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    int x = 0;
    for(List<Object> lo : dataList)
    {  
    if(x == row)
        lo.set(col, value);
    }   
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
   }

    @Override
  public String getColumnName(int col) {
  return header[col];
  }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {   
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }              
        }
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return col != 1;
    }

  @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
    System.out.println(" this is cell value " + data);
   }

   public void fillCourseDialogue()
   {       cl = new Object[dataList.get(0).size()];
        int x = 0;        

        for (List<Object> dl : dataList) {           
         cl[x] = dl.get(1);
         x++;
      }
      }

        @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {  
    JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
    int col = target.getSelectedColumn();
    if(row > -1 && col > 0)
    {   
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SELECT A COURSE","COURSE",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE ,
                                   null,cl, cl[1]);
      }     
       }  
        }                    

     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of  
     generated
      methods, choose Tools | Templates.
      }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated
    methods, choose Tools | Templates.
      }

      @Override
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated
     methods, choose Tools | Templates.
     }

     @Override
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated 
      methods, choose Tools | Templates.
     }          
     }
```

Comment: _I do not want to use the_ `JTable` _class_. What view component will you use in its place? Also consider using a [`CellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow. 3) A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: mouse listener could be used for visible Object on the screen, for view, model is designated to store value for view